# how can i skip blank values in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict:

```
x = {'a': {'p': 'in-gaap', 'r': 'inr', 'dec': 0},
     'b': {'p': 'in-ca', 'r': 'inr', 'dec': 0},
     'c': {'p': 'in-gaap', 'r': '', 'dec': ''},
     'd': {'p': 'in-gaap', 'r': 'inr', 'dec': 0}}
```

i am using this code to skip blank values:

```
for k,v in x.iteritems():
    if d[k]['r'] == '' and d[k]['dec'] == '':
        print k, x[k]['p']
    else:                
        print x[k]['p'], x[k]['r'], x[k]['dec']
```

But the output is:

```
a,in-gaap
b,in-ca
c-in-gaap
d-in-gaap
```

it's not executing condition properly, it is printing all values

And I also tried using this code

```
for k,v in x.iteritems():
    obj = re.match('\w+', x[k]['p'])
    obj1 = re.match('\w+', x[k]['q'])
    if not obj1 and obj2:
        print k, x[k]['p']
    else:                
        print x[k]['p'], x[k]['r'], x[k]['dec']
```

But output is same as above.

Actually the blank values of dict contains `"\n"`, `''`, etc. and some non-ascii characters so I tried using `re`, but it's not executing properly.

Comment: 9 Questions and not able to use formatting? [Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: See how nice it does look now! Thanks @Rik Poggi

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Given the code posted could not compile (unterminated string literals, etc.) This question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 4):

In your first code you are referring to a dict named `d`, which we have no idea what it is. If I rename your dict to `d` instead of `x`, I get this output:

```
>>> ## working on region in file /usr/tmp/python-30572oWE...
in-gaap inr 0
c in-gaap
in-ca inr 0
in-gaap inr 0
```

Which seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
for k,v in x.iteritems():
    if not v['r'] and not v['dec']:
        print k,v['p']
    else:
        print v['p'],v['r'],v['dec']
```

Outputs:

```
in-gaap inr 0
c in-gaap
in-ca inr 0
in-gaap inr 0
```

Comment: careful .. v['dec'] seems to take two different types of falsey values (int 0 and empty string)